# Returning wrong values with if in python in DEF() statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

i started python 3.0 recently, and have been coding a Hazard casino game, and im using an if statement like this:

```
def starthazard():
global chips
Main = input ("Main")
time.sleep(0.1)
if Main == "?" :
print("                                Hazard Rules...                         ")
time.sleep(0.5)
print("You can main 6,7,8 or 9. The main your luckiest number")
time.sleep(0.5)
print("Nicks is winning either 3 / 1 if main is rolled but 1 / 2 if chance is rolled.")
print("Rolling your main is nicks")
print("2 or 3 is thrown out")
time.sleep(0.5)
print("with a main of 5 or 9, you throw out with both an 11 and a 12")
print("with a main of 6 or 8, you throw out with an 11 but nick with a 12")
print("with a main of 7, you nick with an 11 but throw out with a 12")
print("Other numbers are Chance, Roll again but this time main is out and Chance is nicks")
time.sleep(6.9)
Main = input ("Main")
Bet = input("you have " + str (chips) + " chips, what bet would you like to 
place?")
dice1HAZARD = random.randint(1,6)
dice2HAZARD = random.randint(1,6)
RESULTHAZARD = dice2HAZARD + dice1HAZARD
print("first dice is... " + str (dice1HAZARD))
time.sleep(1)
print("second dice is " + str (dice2HAZARD))
time.sleep(1)
print("therefore your number is "+ str (RESULTHAZARD))
time.sleep(1)
if RESULTHAZARD == 2 or 3 :
  print("THROWN OUT! MINUS " + Bet + " Chips" )
  chips = chips - int (Bet)
  PLAYAGAIN = input("play again? Y/N")
  if PLAYAGAIN == "Y":
    starthazard()
  else:
    PICKGAME()
if RESULTHAZARD == Main :
  print("NICKS 3/1!")
  CHIPSWON = Bet * 3
  chips = chips + CHIPSWON
  PLAYAGAIN = input("play again? Y/N")
  if PLAYAGAIN == "Y":
    starthazard()
  else:
    starthazard()
def CHANCECHECK():
  if RESULTHAZARD != Main or 2 or 3 or 11 or 12:
    print("CHANCE" + str (RESULTHAZARD) )
    dice1HAZARD = random.randint(1,6)
    dice2HAZARD = random.randint(1,6)
    RESULTHAZARD = dice2HAZARD + dice1HAZARD
    print("first dice is... " + str (dice1HAZARD))
    time.sleep(1)
    print("second dice is " + str (dice2HAZARD))
    time.sleep(1)
    print("therefore your number is "+ str (RESULTHAZARD))
    time.sleep(1)
    CHANCECHECK()
```

Why is this returning this :
Main 7

you have 800 chips, what bet would you like to place? 10

first dice is... 6

second dice is 1

therefore your number is 7

THROWN OUT! MINUS 10 Chips

play again? Y/N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If RESULTHAZARD is 2, `RESULTHAZARD == 2 or 3` evaluates to `True or 3` which evaluates to `True`. Otherwise, `RESULTHAZARD == 2 or 3` evaluates to `False or 3` which evaluates to `3`, which is a truthy value.

You need to explicitly compare both for equality. Either with `RESULTHAZARD == 2 or RESULTHAZARD == 3`, or `RESULTHAZARD in (2, 3)`.

For the `!=` operator, either several checks connected with `and`, or use `not in` with the sequence of values of interest.

Comment: what about for the != statement